# Laravel 5.1 API redirects ALL requests to /home after a user have registered

Tags: ajax, api, redirect, laravel-5, response

I have the weirdest problem ever...

Currently I have 2 routes in my laravel 5.1 project which i will use as my api.

```
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
```

First time I make an ajax call from my front-end to the 'register' route, everything works as expected.

However, if I make another ajax call to ANY laravel route, it redirects me to the 'home' route.

My code:

AuthController:

```
public function postRegister(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
     User::createUser($request);

     return response()->json();
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    if (!Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return response()->json()->setStatusCode(403);
    }

    return response()->json();
}
```

Model:

```
public static function createUser($data)
{
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'f_name' =>             $data->f_name,
        'l_name' =>             $data->l_name,
        'gender' =>             $data->gender,
        'email' =>              $data->email,
        'birth_date' =>         $data->birth_date,
        'password' =>           bcrypt($data->password),
        'activation_code' =>    $data->activation_code
    ]);
}
```

Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: Api.route('register'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: requestData,
        statusCode: {
            200: function()
            {
                console.log('register: 200');
            },
            422: function()
            {
                console.log('register: 422');
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried:

- making the first ajax call, then commenting out everything in the controller to only return a string, but it still redirects me to the 'home' route on the second request.
- If i comment out the "DB::insert(...)" it works like expected.
- If I make the "DB::insert()" without any data it also works like expected.
- If i make the "DB::insert()" with any single field it redirects on the second call.
- If I use the default Request instead of my custom request it's still redirecting.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any `middleware`?

Comment: I use laravels default middleware for the AuthController.

      `public function __construct()
      {
            $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
      }`

@pespantelis

Comment: When you say **ANY laravel route**, you mean any route of AuthController?

Comment: Ye, I dont have any other controllers yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `guest` middleware applied to all routes of AuthController, except the `getLogout`.

Hence, any ajax call to these routes it redirects to the `home` route (check the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware), except the `getLogout`.

So, you should logout the user to work like expected.

Set the below route and call it:

```
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogout');
```

Or logout the user manually:

```
Auth::logout();
```